# What happens (in terms of pressure) when there is a leakage in a horizontal pipe?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

Consider a horizontal pipe that has water being pumped continuously through it, with a leak at a given point. What will the leak's effect be on the pressure in the pipe, both above and below it in the flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pressure in a horizontal pipe will be the same everywhere when there is no flow.

Due to friction with the inner wall of the pipe, some pressure is required to maintain a constant flow.  Therefore, the pressure in a horizontal pipe will decrease with distance from the pump when there is flow.

Comment: then what will happen when there is a leakage

Comment: @phys: Leakage is just a little current.  There will be a linear drop in pressure from the pump to the leakage point, proportional to the leakage flow.  In many cases, something called "leakage" will be such low flow that there is no relevant pressure drop, or the drop is below your ability to measure.

Comment: Now That clears up my head thankyou